# Format date with Ordinal Number Suffix

Tags: javascript

I would like to format my date as the following, f.ex.: `Thursday, May 2nd 2019`.

I created the following function:

```js
function convertDateToString(date) {
  let monthNames = [
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"
  ];

  let dayNames = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

  let dayIndex = date.getDate();
  let monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  let year = date.getFullYear();

  return dayNames[dayIndex] + ', ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + dayIndex + ' ' + year;
}

let date = new Date()

console.log(convertDateToString(date));

// wanted format: Thursday, May 2nd 2019
```

However, I am not sure how to add the ordinal number suffix to the date. I currently only get the full number and not the `1st`, `2nd` etc.

Any suggestions how to add this?`

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function which takes in the day of the month, eg `2`, and returns the appropriate suffix, eg `nd` (or `st` in the case of `1` (or 21 or 31), `rd` in the case of `3` (or 23), and `th` in all other cases):

```js
const getSuffix = (num) => {
  const suffixes = {
    '1': 'st',
    '21': 'st',
    '31': 'st',
    '2': 'nd',
    '22': 'nd',
    '3': 'rd',
    '23': 'rd'
  };
  return suffixes[num] || 'th';
};
function convertDateToString(date) {
  let monthNames = [
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"
  ];

  let dayNames = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

  let dayIndex = date.getDate();
  let monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  let year = date.getFullYear();

  return dayNames[dayIndex] + ', ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + dayIndex + getSuffix(dayIndex) + ' ' + year;
}

let date = new Date()

console.log(convertDateToString(date));

// wanted format: Thursday, May 2nd 2019
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
// Takes a number and return with ordinal suffix
const ordinal = (n) => {
  const s = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'];
  const m = n % 100;
  return n + (s[(m - 20) % 10] || s[m] || s[0]);
};

// See for yourself
for (let i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
    console.log(ordinal(i));
}
```

Comment: Very useful for that 49th day of the month

Comment: Obviously a partial solution - besides it shouldn't be the responsibility of this function to validate dates.

Comment: Just teasing you on your sample lol. This is the one I went with .

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of suffixes.

```js
function convertDateToString(date) {
  let monthNames = [
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"
  ];
  let suffix = ['st','nd','rd',...Array(13).fill('th'),'st','nd','rd',Array(7).fill('th'),'st']
  let dayNames = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

  let dayIndex = date.getDate();
  let monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  let year = date.getFullYear();

  return dayNames[dayIndex] + ', ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + dayIndex + suffix[dayIndex-1] + ' ' + year;
}

let date = new Date()

console.log(convertDateToString(date));

// wanted format: Thursday, May 2nd 2019
```

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that any time you deal with dates, it's worth considering including [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) - it's a library that makes working with dates much simpler.

You can format your display in the following manner:

```js
function convertDateToString(date) {
  return moment(date)
    .format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY")
}

let date1 = new Date("2019-05-01T10:00:00")
let date2 = new Date("2019-05-02T10:00:00")
let date3 = new Date("2019-05-03T10:00:00")
let date4 = new Date("2019-05-04T10:00:00")

console.log(convertDateToString(date1));
console.log(convertDateToString(date2));
console.log(convertDateToString(date3));
console.log(convertDateToString(date4));

// wanted format: Thursday, May 2nd 2019
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

For more formatting options, [you can check the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/).